# Ambari hortonworks unable to retrieve cpu and memory related information

Tags: amazon-ec2, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to follow this setup in Amazon EC2 + VPC but I get a warning message in the confirm host step:

*All bootstrapped hosts registered but unable to retrieve cpu and memory related information hortonworks*

The problem is that next button is disabled and cannot continue with the installation[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use root / are sure to have sudo rights in place for the user used in the installation?

Comment: yep Teodor. I'm running the instalation as root user